# Does the word "decisiveness" exist?

Tags: word-usage

Does the word "decisiveness" exist ? for example "to deliver an issue with decisiveness OR impactfullness "

Comment: Welcome to ELL.   We ask that you consult a dictionary before asking basic questions of meaning or word-existence like this one. It is easy to determine that the word **decisiveness** does exist. Or did you mean to ask about **impactfulness**?

Comment: It not only exists, but can be used in the way you used it.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the word decisiveness exist?

Yes.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/decisiveness
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/decisiveness?s=t

Comment: You're correct, but please don't encourage obvious "look it up in the dictionary" questions.

Comment: @stangdon , you are also correct. However it's slightly funny or ironic that on this very page now in the right column I see "BLOG: Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change."  which includes  “Be welcoming, be patient," etc etc

Comment: @sam *Especially* when the area of Stack Exchange is one meant to help people who are new to English. If it's the same person who always asks dictionary questions, that's fair. But I see no reason to penalize someone who's completely new to this forum and who has never asked such a question before.